# Will British Airways compensate if my entertainment screen was defective for an entire flight?

Tags: air-travel, british-airways, in-flight-services

I was wondering will I get a compensate if the screen was not working the entire flight from London to LA through the British airlines? I did report the issue.

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/19427/will-airlines-compensate-me-if-my-entertainment-system-is-not-working?rq=1 this question could help in context, but has no specified company

Comment: related: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nUBtKNzoKZ4&t=90 (yeah...turns out he's a bad person but still...his commentary is applicable ;)

Comment: I take it you were not charged any fee specific to using the screen?

Answer (score 23):

**Maybe**, but almost certainly not in cash, and not if you don't follow up.

If you send a feedback form from the website, describe the issue, note that you reported it *and* the crew was unable to fix the issue, you will likely get a small token of compensation like frequent flyer miles, a duty free shopping voucher or a flight voucher.  (A better airline would have given this on the spot, but this is British Airways, not Singapore Airlines...).  You're not legally owed anything though, so be polite, factual and brief.

Comment: I've had exactly this problem with BA, reported it, and got a small but non-trivial amount in duty-free vouchers in return.

Comment: I recall I got $50 in duty-free vouchers on the spot from Singapore Airlines on a long-haul. Given the in-flight shopping prices and the selection, it was probably worth, to me, $10 on the ground. I seem to remember from the voucher, it was $100 in business and $150 in first. This was around 7 years ago.

Answer (score 4):

Doubtful.  You bought a plane ticket, not a ticket to a theater.  On a long flight, you could argue that lack of food was a hardship.  But lack of entertainment??

Comment: The IFE is advertised as part of the services provided on the flight, thus not providing the service without some form of compensation is basically false advertising. People do select airlines based on IFE, which is why they put these expensive systems in to begin with. Further, in premium classes, a bigger screen and fancy headphones are among the reasons why you pay 2x or more, and subsequently they result in better compensation.

Comment: It is true that the BA is not *legally required* to provide IFE. No such guarantee will be found in the CoC or EC T&C or fare rules. That is not the same as saying BA does not, as a customer service matter, have an interest in providing some kind of compensation in the form of a voucher or frequent flyer miles. I got, I think, 2500 United miles once for my reading light not working. I'd much have preferred the light had worked, but I'd much prefer the 2500 miles over nothing.

Comment: Oh sure, good customer service can sometimes get you no end of compensation.  But that depends on your persuasiveness rather than any rule, much less law

Comment: @GeorgeM You don't need to be "persuasive" at all. Simply stating the facts ("I was flying XX0000 on 14-May-2019 in seat 1A and the IFE was inoperative the entire flight despite the efforts of the cabin crew…") will get you *something* based on [internal schedules](http://theforwardcabin.com/2018/01/31/issues-compensated-americans-new-isolve-program/) major airlines maintain. Again, this isn't a contractual obligation, just a guideline. I'm cynical about airline service, too (former United FF), but I'm not going to leave miles on the table for it.

Comment: @user71659 flown numerous times, never was the presence of a functional IFE system listed as one of the items I paid for on the contract.

Comment: @jwenting BA has a [whole site](https://entertainment.ba.com/en/) detailing their IFE system and a tool which specifically looks up what you get on your specific flight. While their conditions of carriage may disclaim IFE availability, contracts do not override legal protections like consumer advertising laws.

Answer (score 2):

What airline ?

You'll probably get (received much later) a voucher of some sorts to buy from the flight store (online shopping).

That's what I got when that happened on a British Airways flight from London to Montréal.

I lost them, it wasn't that much in money anyway.

Comment: what were the procedures? did you rise a compliant?

Comment: I  filled up some paperwork that the flight attendant gave me; received the vouchers a few weeks later, and, as I said, lost them.